# Chrome extension check if url which calls the extension is equal to a specific url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Could anyone explain how I could check if the website im on is equal to a specific site inside a chrome extension?

For example: Im on google.com, so the chrome extension should return: Wrong website.

Im on: youtube.com so the extension should return: Right website.

Hope someone could help since I never really worked on creating a extension for chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some variable to check against:

`var mySiteUrl = 'https://google.com';`

You can then check using the following:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
    if(tab.url === mySiteUrl){
        //it's the right website
    }else{
        //it's not
    }
});
```

If it's a content script, it is running in the context of the current page so you can simply do:

```
if(document.location.href === mySiteUrl){
    //it's the right website
}else{
    //it's not
}
```